# JavaScript function Array.prototype.includes() doesn't work in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a web app that tracks your purchases and displays different statistics. In one of the pages I have jQuery ajax requests that load a user's purchases from an API call. Then all the purchases are put into a global array, called `G_PURCHASES`, as JavaScript objects.

So far so good. Then I call a function that uses jQuery's `Deferred()` to make it chainable; it iterates `G_PURCHASES` and gets all distinct `purchase.item.category`'s (take a look at the purchase object's relevant structure) by checking if `G_PURCHASES[i].item.category` is included in another global array called `G_CATEGORIES` by using `Array.includes()`. And if it is not then `push()` it into `G_CATEGORIES`.

The error I have a problem with is that even after a `category` object has been pushed into the `G_CATEGORIES` array, the `Array.includes()` check still returns `false`, every time. Check the relevant code and output to clear it up.

```
// Relevant structure of the purchase object
purchase = {
  item: {
    category: {
      categoryID: int,
      name: string
    }
}
```

```
// Relevant code

var G_PURCHASES = []; // array declared globally
// it is successfully filled with @purchase objects from another function

var G_CATEGORIES = []; // array declared globally
// to be filled by @LoadAllCategories

var LoadAllCategories = function() {

  // make a jQuery Deffered
  let func = $.Deferred(function() {

    let allP = G_PURCHASES; // make a shortcut
    let allC = C_CATEGORIES; // make another shortcut
    for (var i = 0; i < allP.length; i++) {

      // get whether the current purchase.item.category
      // already exists in allC array
      let exist = allC.includes(allP[i].item.category);

      // console.log the above result
      console.log('i = ' + i + ', category exists = ' + exist);

      // if it doesn't exist then push it in
      if (!exist) allC.push(allP[i].item.category);
    }

    this.resolve();

  });

  return func;
}
```

```
// Input
G_PURCHASES has 6 @purchase objects with 3 unique item.category 'ies

// Output
i = 0, category exists = false
i = 1, category exists = false
i = 2, category exists = false
i = 3, category exists = false
i = 4, category exists = false
i = 5, category exists = false

// Result
G_CATEGORIES contains duplicate categories
```

I tried to use `Array.indexOf()` and jQuery's `$.inArray()` with no success. No matter what I `console.log()` I can't seem to find where the error lies. So, if you can tell me why does `Array.includes()` doesn't work inside this `for` loop I will find you and I will buy you a beer!

Comment: Why not do `console.log(allC, allP[i])` and see what you've got.

Comment: I get an Array and an Object, just as expected:
`Array [ ] Object { item: Object }` `Array [ Object ] Object { item: Object }` `Array [ Object, Object ] Object { item: Object }` and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well includes checks for referential equality, so there might be two objects with same properties and values, but still they are different objects, thus their reference is not equal. You probably want to check every category object for their categoryID and name manually to find duplicates.

Comment: A simple secondary loop iterating the Categories array and checking for categoryID match fixed everything! Thank you!